# Opening different websites from same physical directory, different Default documents in IIS7

Tags: iis-7

How do I open different websites from the same physical directory and different Default documents in IIS7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer [different default documents using rewrite map](http://forums.iis.net/t/1163534.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Hope I uderstood your question corectly.

You have multiple websites which are pointing to the same directory. You want to specify different default document for these websites.

In IIS7

```
Select the website -> Default Document
```

Under "Actions" on the right hand side. Add the default document you want and remove the existing ones.

Comment: Each website should have different Default Document. If i update one it applies to all other as it modifies web.config file.

Comment: Then I think est is to have an common default page (aspx) and then based on the URL redirect to a specific page.

Comment: Sorry. Saw your answer after posting the above comment ;-)